# Is it possible to find $i’(0)$ and $i(0)$ by building and measuring say voltage across the $RLC$ circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance

The RLC circuit equation is,
$$L\frac{\mathrm{d}^2i}{\mathrm{d}t^2}+R\frac{\mathrm{d}i}{\mathrm{d}t}+\frac{1}{C}i=0.$$
I want to know if it is possible to figure out $i’(0)$ and $i(0)$ through the means of building the $RLC$ circuit and measuring values across it using a voltmeter.

Comment: Measure the voltage as a function of time across the **resistor** and from that you can find the current, $i=v/R$, and by measuring the gradient of the current-time graph the rate of change of current can be found.

Comment: A 2nd order diff eq needs two initial conditions, $i(0)$ and $i'(0)$, do you want to measure your initial conditions?

Comment: I agree with Farcher for $i(0)$. For $i’(0)$, just measure the voltage across the inductance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation you presented is for a series RLC. So, following the voltage current laws for each component, it holds:

$$ i(t) = \frac{v_R (t)}{R} = C \frac{dv_C(t)}{dt} = \frac{1}{L}\int_0^t v_L (t) dt + i(0)$$

$$ \frac{di(t)}{dt} = \frac{dv_R (t)}{dt} \frac{1}{R} = C \frac{d^2v_C(t)}{dt^2} = \frac{1}{L}v_L (t)$$

For each instant of time, and in particular for $t=0$. If you measure the voltage in the resistance and in the inductance you can get i(0) and i'(0). I don't see what's the point in doing it: you usually know a priori your initial voltage conditions so you don't need to "measure" them.